Should we have a contest like the "tai chi" one on Marial Arts.SE?
I'm wondering whether we should have a contest like the "tai chi" one on Martial Arts.SE?
In particular, I'm thinking it might be useful if there were a couple of users who know a lot about a particular topic and would be happy to answer resulting questions.
For example, I feel like I know a fair bit about 

psychometric testing in selection and recruitment 
intelligence, personality, and acquiring expertise

Anyway, those are just some examples. I'm wondering whether we should have a contest to promote the site in such a way?
Also, does anyone have an area of expertise where they'd like to receive questions?

It would be great if it involved answering unanswered questions somehow.

@ChuckSherrington ideally a contest should bring in a lot more activity, views and or users. I don't think unanswered questions are our biggest concern at this point. At the same time, it's not as easy to create a view-creating contest for cog sci as it is for Gaming ect, where thousands of people are already looking...

@BenBrocka Ah, like "Relationship Psychology Week" or something like that.  That would draw a lot of views.  I don't know if we really have any experts, though.

@ChuckSherrington more importantly we'd need somewhere to advertise it...
